# Hashing + salting emails used in authentication - good or bad practice?

Tags: django, security, authentication, hash, salt

Is hashing + salting of email addresses and usernames not a normal thing to do? Like in a data breach you wouldn't be able to know who is registrered to the service since every field is hashed + salted? Is there any cons to this since there isnt much about it on the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is **not** standard practice to salt and hash usernames / email addresses.

It is true that an attacker will be unable to identify the stored usernames/ email addresses if salted and hashed prior to storage. In fact, ***nobody*** will be able to access the usernames/ emails (including authorized users like the system administrator).

- **Sounds secure, so why is this a problem?**

When a user attempts to login, they will send a username (or email) and password. Since each salt is unique to that specific username, the only way to associate the username/email with the stored hash username/email is to **test every salt + hash combination until either a match is found or every entry is tried / rejected.**

While this might be possible for a database consisting of few users, it is infeasible in practice because hashing is computationally demanding. Imagine waiting hours or days for a login service to compute every salt+hash combination only to find the username was simply misspelled.

*Additionally, if you are salting usernames then how will you prevent duplicates?*

Usernames must be unique. If you salt the username then you have no way of preventing multiple users from using the same username.

- **What other methods can a developer employ to protect information?**

The most obvious solution is database encryption. While this is a bit outside the scope of your question, [Wikipedia has a good article covering this topic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_encryption)

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Appreciate it! Makes sense!

Comment: @bsheps, what if you use the same salt for all entries? You say "Since each salt is unique to that specific username" - and it would make sense if you use it for passwords. But in this case, the intention is to conceal the actual email addresses.

Comment: You don't want to reuse salt. For example, if 2 users (user1, user2) have the same password + salt, the hashed value will be the same. If an attacker knows user1's plaintext password + hashed password, then the attacker can infer user2 has same password. Further info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)#Salt_re-use

Answer (score 0):

It is not common to hash and salt usernames and email addresses for several reasons:

**Usability**

If your email address was hashed, the website could not display your email address as the value is hashed.

**Security**

From a security standpoint, you wouldn't gain much by hashing your email address. Imagine if somebody had access to your email address, they could use the same hashing algorithm and find your credentials easily by iterating through the database. That is why some website have implemented a separate *login authenticating name and display name*. The login name remains hashed (unsalted) while the display name is stored unhashed. Unless the attacker has your login name/address, there is no way of compromising your data. In this particular case, hashing of email addresses guarantees full security of your data.